# Moving a rigid body in the direction it's facing in Unity and C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I've been trying to get this working using pretty much every method I can find (even using the dreaded transform.translate) but I just can't seem to get it working. This is just a draft of the code and if there are any other ways to go about it I'm down to change some stuff.

Currently, he barely moves (it looks like he's getting stuck on the floor somehow.) I'm fairly new to moving objects using rigid bodies so I'm pretty much in the dark on how to solve this issue.

Here's the script from my latest crack at it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Vector3 movement;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
    {
        movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
            moveCharacter(movement);
    }

    void moveCharacter(Vector3 direction)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have your moveCharacter function inside your Update function, enclosed is the fixed one, which should work now. Before your FixedUpdate was not getting called, therefore your moveCharacter function was not as well and your GameObject was not moving.

- EDIT 1: You shoud also multiply with your movement direction as well, updated the script to fit that
- EDIT 2: I misplaced the curly brackets, fixed that now
- EDIT 3: You should also update your movement Vector3 every frame, not if W is pressed, fixed the script again.
- EDIT 4: Fixed the movement bug (copy and paste entire script, since i changed more lines)

This is the updated script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Vector3 movement;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 1f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveCharacter(movement);
    }

    void moveCharacter(Vector3 direction)
    {
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(movement.x * transform.position.x, movement.y * transform.position.y, movement.z * transform.position.z);
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (offset * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

References: [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

Comment: Im at work right now so i cant test it, but im dying to. Thanks for your help! Im pretty new to this (clearly lol) if you wouldnt could you elaborate on edit 3? Im just curios if/why its better to call the vector rather than just having it in the if statement.

Comment: No worries, just tell me if you tried it, if it worked or not

Comment: For the 3rd edit: if you just update the vector if W is pressed then you only could move if you pressed W, the movement vector would not be set to zero, because it only gets updated if W is pressed, so your movement would not work

Comment: Just pasted it in there and its telling me that the operand cant be used with 2 vector 3s (the bold part)

rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (**movement * transform.forward** * speed * Time.deltaTime));

Comment: Ah, i think it should be **movement + transform.forward** try replacing the * with a +

Comment: Ah, no, that wont work, ill fix this as soon as im home, give me an hour or so

Comment: Typed some code on my mobile phone, so don’t know, if it works, ill check is as soon as im home. Feel free to test it, updated code is in answer, just make sure, you copy and paste the whole script, since i changed more.

Answer (score 0):

```
public float TurnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
public float turnSmoothVelocity;   

void Update()
{

    // Detect input WASD
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    // Get angle for horizontal mouse
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
    float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
    float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, TurnSmoothTime);

    // Get angle for vertical mouse
    float verticalAngle = cam.eulerAngles.x;

    // Check if WASD are being pressed
    if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f){

        // CHARACTER ROTATES ONLY ON THE HORIZONTAL PLANE, USUALLY WHEN IT IS GROUNDED
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

        // IF YOU WANT YOUR CHARACTER TO ROTATE BOTH HORIZONTAL AND VERTICAL, USE
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(verticalAngle, angle, 0f);

    }
}
```